# Manipulate button, that triggers function returning random value, doesn't recall the function on each click

Tags: manipulate, front-end, color, gui-construction

I've created a piece of code that returns random color scheme:

```
getRandomColor = ColorData["Gradients"][[RandomInteger[{1, 51}]]]
```

Now, I'm trying to use it with my `Manipulate`, `ArrayPlot`, to generate random color schemes to be applied to the plot:

```
Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[SierpinskiCarpet@iterations, Frame -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> color],
 {iterations, 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {color, {"AlpineColors", "ArmyColors", 
   blackAndWhite -> "Black & White", getRandomColor -> "Random"}}]
```

It does work only once, then it doesn't reevaluate the `color`, on `Random` button click, but sticks with the value, that was generated on the first click.
How to cope with that?

Comment: Thanks! You may want to post it as an answer!

Comment: Yes, I did notice that. Also, there is the thing that when I slide the slider, the function gets triggered on each slider's step. I wouldn't say that it's a good thing, it's definitely not what I expected, but it's not a crucial bug for me nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getRandomColor[] := ColorData["Gradients"][[RandomInteger[{1, 51}]]]

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> color], 
 {color, {"AlpineColors", "ArmyColors", "Random"}, 
  TrackingFunction :> ((color = If[# === "Random", getRandomColor[], #]) &)
 }
]
```

Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.